# Tracking down pesky PHP 5.3 errors

Tags: debugging

We have a site that is throwing errors when uploading files to a simple "Page" node. I've done a lot of work trying to track down the actual source of the error, and I posted a half dozen messages to various likely threads at drupal.org.

The errors we get on file attach/upload:

> warning: Parameter 2 to wysiwyg_form_alter() expected to be a
>   reference, value given  in /var/www/drupal/includes/common.inc on line
>   2892.
>
> warning: Parameter 2 to simple_access_form_alter() expected to be a
>   reference, value given in /var/www/drupal/includes/common.inc on line
>   2892.

I understand about passing by reference versus value. I understand about fixing the problem in the offending module by using the two calls to `drupal_alter()`, as described on
http://drupal.org/node/930992#comment-4066840, but so far I have not been able to find what module is making the call incorrectly.

I tried installing and enabling the same set of modules on a test site but cannot reproduce these errors.

It's hard to post a bug report when you don't know the offending module.

See also http://drupal.org/node/1200970#comment-5463436.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not have a debugger going (getting XDebug to run for your local development environment is probably the single most useful thing you can do the entire year), you could use [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) at the place of the error (i.e. in the two form alter functions) to find out what is calling them. If you shoot its output into watchdog(), hopefully you can cross reference the time of the error with a particular invocation of these functions. Do be aware that these are form alter hooks, which get called for each and every form Drupal is building (and you might be surprised there can actually be several forms on a single page; just think of search and login forms). I.e. not every call will be the offending one.

Comment: I had already placed a `dsm(debug_backtrace());` at the beginning of the wysiwyg_form_alter function. It showed the following:
[0] wysiwyg_form_alter
[1] call_user_func_array from common.inc (core)
[2] drupal_alter from form.inc (core)
[3] drupal_prepare_form from form.inc (core)
[4] drupal_get_form (from node.pages.inc, core)
[5] node_page_edit
[6] call_user_func_array (menu.inc)
[7] menu_execute_active_handler (index.php)

Comment: Not sure where to go from here, since it seems to be all core stuff, and I thought core was OK with php 5.3.

Comment: It should be, but core can have bugs just like any other piece of software :) I do find a few issues on D.o about your error message (specifically, code going through common.inc line 2892 throwing this error), but there doesn't seem to be a clear cut solution yet.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I applied a patch to common.inc as described in the comment below, and that fixed the problem. I also along the way (in response to other error messages and problems) patched the core upload.module and applied two patches to the private_upload module. Whew! Fixing common.inc based on: http://drupal.org/node/710892#comment-3884210

Thanks for your help Eelke Blok!!

Answer (score 0):

The errors reported are for functions contained, respectively, in the [Wysiwyg](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module and the [Simple Access](http://drupal.org/project/simple_access) module. `wysiwyg_form_alter()` is the implementation of [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) done from the first module, and `simple_access_form_alter()` is the implementation of the same hook done from the second module.

The function names of function implemented from a module are generally prefixed by the short name of the module. In the case of hook implementations, the list of the hooks used by Drupal is listed under [Hooks (Drupal 7)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/group/hooks/7) and [Hooks (Drupal 6)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/group/hooks/6); that helps because the hook name is the second part of the hook implementation.

For example, `wysiwyg_form_alter()` could be the function implemented by a module using "wysiwyg_form" as short name, but looking at the installed modules, you will see that you don't have any "wysiwyg_form.module" file; instead, you have a "wysiwyg.module" file that is generally inside a "wysiwyg" directory.